# Using mappings and bijections for a simple looking probability problem.

Tags: probability, functions

I came across this simple problem today: Show that the probability of rolling a $14$ is the same whether we use $3$ or $5$  fair dice. It is very easy (but tedious)  to solve with basic probability but I wanted to use something a bit more flash (and hopefully cleaner)

Before begging on this puzzle I would like to show you a similar looking puzzle with the method I would like to use to attack the first one.

**Warm up problem:**

$A$ rolls three $6$ sided dice and $B$ rolls one $20$ sided die. Show that the probability $A's$ rolls sum greater than $B$'s roll is equal to the probability $B$ rolls greater than $A$.

We will construct a bijective mapping, $\phi: \mathbb{N}^3 \times \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N}^3 \times \mathbb{N}$, between winning combinations for $A$, denoted the set $W_A$ into winning combinations for $B$, $W_B,$ and thus show the finite sets have the same size. Let $X_1 = \{a_1, a_2, a_3 \} \times\{b_1 \} \in W_A$ denote the rolls that occurred in $A$ winning. In other words:  $a_1+a_2+a_3 > b_1$. Now consider turning over all four dice, (applying $\phi$)  we now see $ \phi(X_1) = \{7-a_1, 7 -a_2, 7-a_3 \} \times \{ 21-b_1\}  \in W_B$ as $7-a_1 + 7-a_2 + 7 -a_3 = 21 - (a_1+a_2+a_3) < 21 - b_1$

And so there is a one-to-one mapping from $W_A \to W_B$ and $W_B \to W_A$ and so they have equal size and we are done.

**My problem**

I cannot help but wonder that there is a very similar method for my puzzle above. Denoting $S_n \subset \mathbb{N}^n$  as combinations of $n$ rolls that sum to $14$ ,I envision it as follows:

Let $\{x_1,x_2,x_3 \} \in S_3$ be a combination of rolls that sum to $14$. We need to show there are $36$ as many rolls in $S_5$

i.e for any $\{x_1,x_2,x_3 \}$ and any $2$ rolls of a dice we can construct a unique element of $S_5$.

I initially had it like this: $\phi: \mathbb{N}^3 \times \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}^5$ by "absorbing the final two rolls into earlier states" as required:

Consider $S_3 \ni \{6,5,3 \}$ $\times \{2,3 \} \to \{6,2,1,2,3 \}$ as we pushed right to left by taking $2$ from $3$ to give $1$ and then $3$ from $5$ to give $2$

This fails to work however as it is not injective nor subjective. Consider $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \times \{6,5\}$. $\phi$ will always take it to $\{1,1,1,6,5 \}$. Also $\{6,6\}$ will never be a suitable input for the $\mathbb{N}^2$ part.

Can someone think of a nice way to do this?